# Trigger cocoon add_association from javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, cocoon-gem

I am using cocoon and I want to automatically add a child record when a date(can be multiple dates) in a date picker is selected.

I can trap the date selections in coffeescript like this, but I don't know how to get a child record added through cocoon i.e. by emulating what happens when the link_to_add_association is fired.

```
$(".form_multidate").datepicker().on 'changeDate', (e) -> alert(e.dates)
```

the cocoon setup is a standard nested form, no tricks, working fine on the page.

EDIT: Code mentioned in comment re binding calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#other_request_details')
    .bind('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
      return $('.datepicker-single').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "DD, dd M yy"
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nope, I ended up doing something different. I suspect you need to bind to one of the cocoon methods. I use something similar to reload a jquery calendar:

Comment: Just trigger the click event on the `link_to_add_association` element should do it?

Answer (score 1):

Calling a JS function in order to add a new record with Cocoon is not possible. The only thing you can do is trigger the click event of the add association button.

[If you see Cocoon's library code you will see that all new record functionality is bound to the click button](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/cocoon.js)

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.add_fields', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this                 = $(this),
        assoc                 = $this.data('association'),
        assocs                = $this.data('associations'),
        content               = $this.data('association-insertion-template'),
        insertionMethod       = $this.data('association-insertion-method') || $this.data('association-insertion-position') || 'before',
        insertionNode         = $this.data('association-insertion-node'),
        insertionTraversal    = $this.data('association-insertion-traversal'),
        count                 = parseInt($this.data('count'), 10),
        regexp_braced         = new RegExp('\\[new_' + assoc + '\\](.*?\\s)', 'g'),
        regexp_underscord     = new RegExp('_new_' + assoc + '_(\\w*)', 'g'),
        new_id                = create_new_id(),
        new_content           = content.replace(regexp_braced, newcontent_braced(new_id)),
        new_contents          = [];


    if (new_content == content) {
      regexp_braced     = new RegExp('\\[new_' + assocs + '\\](.*?\\s)', 'g');
      regexp_underscord = new RegExp('_new_' + assocs + '_(\\w*)', 'g');
      new_content       = content.replace(regexp_braced, newcontent_braced(new_id));
    }

    new_content = new_content.replace(regexp_underscord, newcontent_underscord(new_id));
    new_contents = [new_content];

    count = (isNaN(count) ? 1 : Math.max(count, 1));
    count -= 1;

    while (count) {
      new_id      = create_new_id();
      new_content = content.replace(regexp_braced, newcontent_braced(new_id));
      new_content = new_content.replace(regexp_underscord, newcontent_underscord(new_id));
      new_contents.push(new_content);

      count -= 1;
    }

    var insertionNodeElem = getInsertionNodeElem(insertionNode, insertionTraversal, $this)

    if( !insertionNodeElem || (insertionNodeElem.length == 0) ){
      console.warn("Couldn't find the element to insert the template. Make sure your `data-association-insertion-*` on `link_to_add_association` is correct.")
    }

    $.each(new_contents, function(i, node) {
      var contentNode = $(node);

      insertionNodeElem.trigger('cocoon:before-insert', [contentNode]);

      // allow any of the jquery dom manipulation methods (after, before, append, prepend, etc)
      // to be called on the node.  allows the insertion node to be the parent of the inserted
      // code and doesn't force it to be a sibling like after/before does. default: 'before'
      var addedContent = insertionNodeElem[insertionMethod](contentNode);

      insertionNodeElem.trigger('cocoon:after-insert', [contentNode]);
    });
  });
```